# Jquery scrollup hover stop

Tags: jquery, html, animation, scroll

Quick question.

Trying to make a hoverable scroll control for my site. I want the page to scroll when you hover over the button rather than when you click it. I have it mostly working but it seems a little glitchy mainly because the hover event continually triggers the animate method. I was wondering if there was a more clean way to trigger it. Below is the code I have so far.

```
    $("#goUp").hover(function () { 
      var curpos= $('body').scrollTop();
      $("body").animate({scrollTop: curpos- 200}, 800);
    }, function () {
        // I want to stop the animation here when they mouse out
    });

    $("#goDown").hover(function () { 
      var curpos= $('body').scrollTop();
      $("body").animate({scrollTop: curpos+ 200}, 800);
    }, function () {
        // I want to stop the animation here when they mouse out        
    });
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to stop animation.

```
$("body").stop()
```

Comment: Perfect :D That was what I was missing. Thanks :) I'll flag it in 9 mins when it lets me